# Rotations of Lebesgue measurable sets are Lebesgue measurable

Tags: lebesgue-measure, self-learning, measurable-sets

If $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $Q:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is an orthogonal map, then I know that $\mu^*(QE)=\mu^*(E)$, i.e., the Lebesgue outer measure is invariant under rotations.

Now I would like to show that $E$ is measurable iff $QE$ is measurable, using the Carathéodore criterion.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Rotations are invertible, and $\mu^*(A) = \mu^*(Q^{-1}A)$ for every $A$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I understand, but do I have to use any property of $Q$ over intersections? I still do not understand how could it help.

Comment: You need the fact that any injection distributes over set intersection. I.e., for this case, $Q(A \cap B) = Q(A) \cap Q(B)$ for any pair of sets $(A,B)$. This is straightforward to show.

Comment: Thank you. I helped!